# Algorithm caption color background

Tags: algorithms, algorithmic

I tried to modify my algorithm caption in order to fill it gray.

However, there is some white space left.

Has anyone an idea what the problem is?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\DeclareCaptionFormat{algo}{\colorbox{lightgray}{\parbox{\textwidth}{#1#2#3}}}
\captionsetup[algorithm]{format=algo}


\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Dummy Caption} 
    \footnotesize
    \begin{algorithmic}
        \Require $a$
        \Ensure $b$
        \State $b \gets a$ 
    \end{algorithmic} 
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please don't post code fragments, always make a small, but compilable test file.

Comment: Thanks for your remark. I updated the code.

Comment: Much better, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems:

- the big space on the top is due to your box being too wide to fit in a line. If you use a `\parbox` of `\textwidth`, then there is no room for the additional 2 `\fboxsep` which gets added by your coloured box.
- once this is fixed, there is only a tiny gap above and below. To remove this as well, you could use this quick hack:

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\DeclareCaptionFormat{algo}{\colorbox{lightgray}{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep}{#1#2#3}}}
\captionsetup[algorithm]{format=algo}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\fs@ruled{\def\@fs@cfont{\bfseries}\let\@fs@capt\floatc@ruled
  \def\@fs@pre{\hrule height.8pt depth0pt \kern2pt \vskip-2pt}%
  \def\@fs@post{\kern2pt\hrule\relax}%
  \def\@fs@mid{\vskip-2pt \kern2pt\hrule\kern2pt}%
  \let\@fs@iftopcapt\iftrue}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Dummy Caption} 
    \footnotesize
    \begin{algorithmic}
        \Require $a$
        \Ensure $b$
        \State $b \gets a$ 
    \end{algorithmic} 
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Dummy Caption Dummy Caption Dummy Caption Dummy Caption Dummy Caption Dummy Caption Dummy Caption Dummy Caption Dummy Caption Dummy Caption Dummy Caption Dummy Caption Dummy Caption Dummy Caption } 
    \footnotesize
    \begin{algorithmic}
        \Require $a$
        \Ensure $b$
        \State $b \gets a$ 
    \end{algorithmic} 
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! It works :)

Comment: @Marcel You're welcome!